# Java Object return type vs. Generic Methods

Tags: java, generics

I saw several questions about generic return type, but none answers my question.

If there is no bound for any of the arguments, such as the following method in [JayWay](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.java) :

```
public static <T> T read(String json, String jsonPath, Filter... filters) {
    return new JsonReader().parse(json).read(jsonPath, filters);
}
```

What is the point of using this as generic ?
I told the guys from my team that this method should be used as :

```
JsonPath.<Boolean>read(currentRule, "$.logged")
```

instead of:

```
(boolean) JsonPath.read(currentRule, "$.logged")
```

But I really can't tell the difference...

Comment: After type-erasure, I don't think there is a difference.

Comment: Nothing in the method body ostensibly uses the type variable `T`. How would  `JsonPath.<Boolean>read(currentRule, "$.logged")` safely return a `Boolean` but `JsonPath.<String>read(currentRule, "$.logged")` safely return a `String`?

Comment: Would you be willing to change the cast to a `Boolean` to avoid dragging autoboxing into the question?

Comment: Actually, I see no advantage in generics here. As said before, T is never used.

Comment: @JFMeier the major disadvantage is that the unchecked cast is hidden in the [`read`](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.java#L171) method, rather than it being right there in your face to show you you are doing something type-iffy.

Comment: In this case make use of `T` also get influenced by the implementation of `JsonPath.<T>read` method. If you use `T`, inside the code will just do the same `return (T)res;` but the code validates if you read an Array will handle differently and cast it to any IEnumerable implemented class you passed on `T`. If you want to pass object on `T` will work but the could be anything `Boolean`, `Integer`, `List`, etc. In simple words if you know the type, it will save you the cast instruction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generics work by the compiler inserting invisible casts into your code.

For example, before generics were added to the language you'd have to do this.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Foo");
list.add("Bar");
String str0 = (String) list.get(0);
String str1 = (String) list.get(1);
```

This was very annoying. Because `get()` returned `Object`, you had to cast every single time you wanted to get a `String` from the `List`.

Nowadays, `List` is generic, and `get()` returns `T`, so you can just do this.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Foo");
list.add("Bar");
String str0 = list.get(0);
String str1 = list.get(1);
```

What is happening here is that the compiler turns the new version into the old version by adding the casts for you, but they're still there.

However, the entire point of generics is that these compiler generated casts are *guaranteed to be safe* - i.e. they can't possibly throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

In my opinion, if you use generics to hide casts that are *not* guaranteed to be safe, just because they're annoying, it is an abuse of the feature.

Whether it's a generic method and you do

```
Boolean a = JsonPath.<Boolean>read(currentRule, "$.logged");
```

or it returns `Object` and you do

```
Boolean a = (Boolean) JsonPath.read(currentRule, "$.logged");
```

*both* versions could throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, so I think it's better if you are forced to cast so that at least you are aware that you're doing something that could fail.

I consider it bad practice for the return type of a generic method to involve the type parameter `T`  if the method parameters do not, *unless* the returned object cannot be used in a way that compromises type safety. For example,

```
public static <T> List<T> emptyList()
```

in `Collections` is ok (the list is empty so it can't contain an element of the wrong type).

In your case, I think the `read` method should not be generic and should just return `Object`.

Comment: the `read` method is a 3rd party library i'm using. how would you use it if yo were in my place ? cast it yourself or let cast it internally and catch `ClassCastException` ?

Comment: @Nati I would use do `Boolean a = JsonPath.<Boolean>read` or `Boolean a = JsonPath.read`, and leave a comment in the code saying `//warning: this method involves an unsafe cast!`.

Comment: That advice is pretty much the same as AndyTurner's (leave a comment and use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, except that there actually isn't a warning to supress.

Comment: From what i've seen so far - there isn't much difference, if any. unchecked casting in invadable, so it's pretty much a styling issue !

Comment: That's correct - it's purely a matter of opinion and style, and looking at these answers there's obviously a split. The unavoidable fact is that calling that method and assigning it to a `Boolean` (whether you use `(Boolean)`, `<Boolean>` or neither), you could get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason that I would stay away from

```
JsonPath.<Boolean>read(currentRule, "$.logged")
```

is that it is internally performing an unchecked cast, and hiding this fact. For instance, you could invoke this method at the same place:

```
JsonPath.<String>read(currentRule, "$.logged")
```

and there is no way that you'd know there might be a problem there until it actually happens at runtime - it still compiles, and you don't even get a warning.

There is no getting away from the unchecked cast - I'd just rather have it right there in front of me in the code, so I know there is a potential danger; this allows me to take reasonable steps to mitigate the issue.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // I know something might go wrong here!
boolean value = (boolean) JsonPath.read(currentRule, "$.logged")
```

Comment: Then what you're actually saying that the method better return an `Object` and not be generic since the casting is invadable ?

Comment: @Nati yes. Like I commented above, you don't actually make use of `T`, other than to do the unchecked cast.

Comment: The way the method is declared, he can just do this: `String value = JsonPath.read(currentRule, "$.logged");` It's going to internally perform an unchecked cast either way no matter if you provide an explicit type witness or not.

Answer (score 2):

Having a type-parameter that has never been set (when calling `JsonPath.read(currentRule, "$.logged")`), actually makes the compiler completely ignore all the generic information within the method and replace all the type-parameter with:

- `Object`, if the type-parameter doesn't have an upper-bound. (like in your case)
- `U`, if the type-parameter is bounded like `<T extends U>`. For example, if you have a `<T extends Number>` as a type-parameter and ignore it by calling `JsonPath.read(...)`, then the compiler will replace the type-parameter with `Number`.

In the case with the cast (`(boolean) JsonPath.read(...)`), the type-parameter is replaced with `Object`. Then, this type is unsafely transformated to `boolean`, by first returning a `Boolean` (probably), and then auto-unboxing this wrapper to `boolean`. This is not safe, at all. Actually, every cast is not safe - pretty much you tell the compiler: "I know what this type will be at Runtime, so please believe me, and let me cast it to something else that's compatible with it.". Your humble servant, the compiler, allows that, but that's not safe, if you're wrong. :)

There's another thing with your method, also. The type-parameter is never used within the method body or parameters - this makes it pretty redundant. Since by doing a cast to `boolean` you insist that you know the return type of `new JsonReader().parse(json).read(jsonPath, filters);`, then you should just make the return type `boolean` (or `Boolean`):

```
public static Boolean read(String json, String jsonPath, Filter... filters) {
    return new JsonReader().parse(json).read(jsonPath, filters);
}
```

Comment: This isn't my code, I'm just wondering what is the best way to use it.

Comment: Yours or not, I hope I was helpful. Cheers :)

Comment: What I meant - this is a dependency i'm using, a 3rd party code. would you cast it yourself or pass <Boolean> as a generic ?

Comment: I would set `<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing functionally different between the two. The byte-code will probably be identical.

The core difference is that one uses a cast while the other uses generics.

I would generally try to avoid casting if there is any alternative mechanism and as the generic form is a perfectly effective alternative I would go for that.

```
// The right way.
JsonPath.<Boolean>read(currentRule, "$.logged");
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I think it looks cleaner, though that JayWay internally do cast to (T)...

Comment: @Nati - They **both** do a run-time cast so there is no difference functionally.