# How do you make a generic abstract function that does not return any particular type?

Tags: java

At the moment, I have a superclass called Entity.

```
abstract class Entity {
    private String name;
    private Area area;

    public Entity(String name, Area area) {
        this.name = name;
        this.area = area;
    }

    private static void entityWait() {
        Time.sleep(Random.nextInt(50, 600));
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private Area getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    abstract <T> T getNearest();

    abstract boolean validate();


}
```

As far as I understand, this indicates that T is a generic and the return type can be set to anything.

```
abstract <T> T getNearest();
```

I then have my subclass in which I extend from Entity:

```
public class Mob extends Entity {

private String name;
private Area area;

public Mob(String name, Area area) {
    super(name, area);
}

@Override
Npc getNearest() {
    Npc npc = Npcs.getNearest(name);
    return npc;
}
```

Eventually, I will have a SceneObject and Item class which refers to items in the game world which will require the same functions. So, eventually I'll have to do in the SceneObject class:

```
@Override
SceneObject getNearest() {
    SceneObject object = SceneObjects.getNearest(name);
    return object;
}
```

However, I'm getting an unchecked override warning - return type requires unchecked conversion. What does this mean and how do I do this the correct way?

Comment: Why not just use Object? Return types are covariant. Or you could make T a type parameter to your abstract class

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Is your plan that you could do `Npc npc = abstract.getNearest();`? What if the nearest isn't `Npc` in this case? That would cause a `ClassCastException`, and the compiler is telling you it won't let that happen (unless you explicitly tell it "I don't care, I want to write unsafe code that will break easily").

Comment: I went ahead and added clarification.

Comment: Take a look at this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479539/2928853

Comment: So what other classes can `getNearest()` return besides `Npc`? You could add a generic parameter to `Entity` class, but I'm not sure whether your full design is going to benefit from that. It might solve your immediate problem, but if your design suffers from it, you'll pay for it later with more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your `Entity` class with generic parameters:

```
abstract class Entity<T> {
```

And remove the generic type declaration from your method:

```
abstract T getNearest();
```

And have your subclass extend `Entity` with a generic type:

```
public class Mob extends Entity<Npc> {
```

Comment: Thanks, you're both right and answered at the same time!

Answer (score 3):

You want to declare `Entity` itself as generic:

```java
abstract class Entity<T> {
    private String name;

    ...

    abstract T getNearest();

    ...
}
```

Then your extending class uses the generic parameter:

```java
public class Mob extends Entity<Npc> {

    ...

    @Override
    Npc getNearest() {
       return Npcs.getNearest(name);
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're both right and answered at the same time!

Comment: @MarcelDoe I think George was some seconds faster, so accept his answer. Notice what Kayaman has told you in his comments: It could be the case that making `Entity` generic could be the wrong solution here. If you like, share what other classes extend `Entity` and what the overall idea behind `getNearest` is. Then I could extend my answer to be more than just a plain syntax presentation.

Comment: @MarcelDoe Also notice that `Entity` declares `name`. The extending classes don't need to re-declare it; they inherit `name`. Same goes for `area`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying breaks at least two rules of object oriented programming. You mix class and interface. You expect any subclass of Entity to fulfill an unknown contract to get nearest. If I invoke this method with a type argument of `ArrayList<IllegalStateException>` the subclass must return this type. How can this be known at compile time?

The second is breaking out of the instance' context of Mob by invoking a **static** method `Npcs.getNearest(name)` that does anything…like printing out a sheet of paper on a clerks desk on the other side of the world to get nearest Npc. That person scans in the result and returns it with a carrier pigeon. An optical character recognition tool then kills the pigeon to extract the characters and returns an Npc, or null or a *Runtime Exception* or `OutOfMemoryError`.

I assume you thought about a contract like expressed through an interface and the method `getNearest` returns something, that is determined by the realizer of the method. Thus you need interfaces instead of classes. And it is also unclear, whether there can be a superposition of two different `getNearest` in the same class.

Maybe it is absolutely sufficient to let `SceneObject` have a `getNearest` of its own as well as Mob and not force this through the Entity. Otherwise `getNearest` ought to return something that bears a distance to its source or even any source, so `getNearest` of `SceneObject` can be compared to `getNearest` of `Mob` – what your contract suggests. If this is never the case, drop all evil inheritance.

Comment: I'm sorry, ELI5 please?

Comment: ELI5 means what? Explain like I'm five? Your abstract class Entity expresses formal contracts, e.g. all sub classes of Entity provide a name attribut or a capability/ function/ method to getNearest – whatever that means.

By extending Entity, for example through Mob, it realizes this contract by returning an Npc. In case SceneObject also inherits from Entity it also must fulfill this contract and return some result of getNearest.

It is not clear if both results really belong to the same contract, thus anyMob.getNearest().getDistanceTo(anySceneObject.getNearest()) makes sense.

Comment: Your use of the type parameter in getNearest suggests a different intention. Maybe you mean getNearest() returns something, like an interface, that allows distance computations between totally different things – like a Mob and a SceneObject. If you never calculate such distances then Entity must not define a common capability/ method/ function to getNearest. If you calculate such distances, there'll be an interface Spatial that has a single method like public double distanceTo(Spatial other). And Npc as well as SceneObject implement this interface. (And maybe Area somehow provides boundaries)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Going to delve into interfaces.

Comment: But while writing I assume you simply lack a World or Scene class that owns the getNearest by traversing its inner structure composite of Npc/ SceneObject or whatever. The only way to let the scope be thightly coupled to a single object. (First violation I mentioned.) Maybe the getNearest is between all known SceneObject-instances or Npc-s or even all that have a Area that is to be taken into consideration/ delivers boundaries to calculate with.